# How to change the GRUB select menu key?

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I want to select GRUB menu with a specific key. For example, the first menu key can be selected by pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, the second item can be selected by pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> key, etc...

How I should do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example add hotkey in grub.cfg file
menuentry "Win7" --hotkey=7 --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain`...